# Is there anything wrong with the code in my form?

Tags: php, html, email, post

I'm using this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/send-email/) to create a contact form for my site and it doesn't seem to be working. After I fill in my form and press submit, nothing happens. I would like to know whats wrong with it and how I can fix it.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
    <form action="mail/contact.php" method="post">
                  <div class="row control-group">
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
  <label>Name:</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
  </div></div>
<br />

<div class="row control-group">
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
  <label>Email:</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
  </div></div>
<br />

<div class="row control-group">
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
  <label>Message:</label>
  <textarea name="message" rows="5" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div></div>


<br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
       // from the form
       $name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
       $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
       $message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);

       // set here
       $subject = "Contact form submitted!";
       $to = 'name@mail.com';

       $body = <<<HTML
$message
HTML;

       $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
       $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

       // send the email
       mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

       // popup success
       echo '<script language="javascript">';
       echo 'alert("Your message has been sent!")';
       echo '</script>';

?>
```

Comment: nothing seems to be wrong, maybe the `mail()` method might be the one with a problem

Comment: @JonathanS. so how can i fix it? sorry i'm an amateur

Comment: do you land on `mail/contact.php` after you press submit ?

Comment: Instead of `$body = <<<HTML $message HTML;` use `$body = $message;`

Comment: @Dagon after i press submit, nothing happens. it stays on the same page. when i hover the button, it shows mail/contact.php

Comment: @JonathanS. I did as you said and after pressing submit it still does nothing :(

Comment: Could you please post your folder structure...?

Comment: @JonathanS. http://i.imgur.com/BNuWx84.png

Comment: Are you just opening the file in your browser to run it, or are you loading it from an actual web server?

Comment: @j08691 actual web server

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem actually, you hace to change `$to` to `$email` in the `email()` method because the variable that has the email you want to send to is $email.

Your `contact.php` code will be:

```
<?php
// from the form
$name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
$email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);

// set here
$subject = "Contact form submitted!";

$body = <<<HTML
$message
HTML;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

// send the email
mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);

// popup success
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Your message has been sent!")';
echo '</script>';

?>
```

Another recommendation is to check [this tutorial](http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/create-a-simple-and-secure-contact-form-with-jquery-and-php/) for a secure contact form.

Also you should check out this two php frameworks:

- [Symfony 2 Mail](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/email/email.html)
- [Zend 2 Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mail.message.html)

Comment: To run **php** code you have to run a server like apache, nginx, or something like that... if you're a windows user checkout xampp, or ampps, if you're a mac user, check out mamp.

Comment: im running this on a web server. i tried the code you posted and its still not working

Comment: Describe all your project setup please

Comment: it works for me when i create a separate html page and use the form... but on my index.html, the submit button doesn't do anything for some reason. any idea? :(

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you should check out all your project setup, and add more description of the real project to the post, actually this is a right answer for this post, maybe if you provide more details we could help

Comment: sorry can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by project setup? this is simply just a portfolio website of mine. a one page portfolio, nothing complex

Comment: yeah i know, but there might be other things not working, probably the server, or something you're missing, are you sure that the submit button is working, i mean the action is triggered? are you using jquery?

Comment: i believe jquery is used. does it interfere with php?

Comment: no, but through jquery you can change how every dom element acts, so... what happens when you hit submit button?